# Percentage above a number in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my table that shows how many seconds the customer was in line to be served, in seconds.

I need to put together a query that shows how many percent of chats were served within 30 seconds.

I was only able to count the number of calls over the ideal period, but I couldn't get the percentage of chats that were within that ideal period.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(c.id) AS 'Total'
FROM lh_chat as c
    LEFT JOIN lh_departament as d ON c.dep_id = d.id
    INNER JOIN lh_users u ON c.user_id = u.id
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(c.time-10800, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-31'
    AND u.id != 178
    AND c.`status` <> 0
    AND c.dep_id IN (7,19,23)
    AND c.wait_time > 30
```

I was only able to add the number of chats above the ideal time, but not to make the percentage of chats that are within the expected range

Comment: 30 seconds?  I would abandon your website after 3 seconds.

Comment: SQL Server (MS SQL) and MySQL are two absolutely different DBMSs. Please refine your tags list.

Answer (score 0):

Several things can speed up that query.  Perhaps other queries can be sped up, too.

- You probably want `COUNT(*)` to avoid checking `cd.id IS NOT NULL` before counting.
- The check on c.time is not [*sargable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) ; change to something like

  ```
        c.time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2023-01-01')
    AND c.time  < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2023-01-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  ```
- Deal the the TZ(?) 10800 some other way.
- Have an index *starting* with `time`
- `lh_departament` does not seem to be used; remove it from the query?
- The best way to compute summary information is by building and maintaining a [*Summary Table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) , perhaps daily.